# How to infer computed object keys in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am creating a project in which I want to easily define new plugins and I want to use TypeScript in my IDE to help me use the names of these plugins. I have a folder structure like this:

```
src
│ ...
└── plugins
   └── pluginA
   |     index.ts
   └── pluginB
   |     index.ts
   └── ...
     index.ts <-- "here I want to combine all plugins in one object"
```

Each plugin has a default export in `index.ts` with interface like this:

```js
interface Plugin {
  name: string
  ...
}
```

`src/plugins/pluginA/index.ts`

```js
export default {
  name: "pluginA",
  ...
}
```

`src/plugins/index.ts`

```js
import pluginA from "./pluginA"
import pluginB from "./pluginB"
...

export default {
  [pluginA.name]: pluginA
  [pluginB.name]: pluginB
  ...
}
```

And I want TypeScript to understand what the names of the existing plugins (to infer the Literal type of keys of the plugins).

In other words, I want to use defined plugins in my code like this:

```js
import plugins from "src/plugins"

...

const plugin = plugins["nonExistingPlugin"] // I want the typescript to show error here, since there is no plugin with this name
//                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

const anotherPlugin = plugins["plug_"] // I want the IDE to autocomplete the name of the plugin from the existing ones
//                            "pluginA"
//                            "pluginB"
//                            "..."
```

All my attempts led me to the fact that TypeScript understood that the `name` property of the plugin is a `string`, but didn't infer Literal type.

Can TypeScript do that? And if not, is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried `as const`: `export default { ... } as const`?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, yes I did, but maybe in a wrong way. Where exactly should I put `as const`?

Comment: Ignore my comment. A `const` assertion will not work in this case, unless you define everything (i.e. all plugin objects and the plugins object) `as const`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `as const` assertions here:

```js
const pluginA = {
  name: 'pluginA',
  //
} as const
const pluginB = {
  name: 'pluginB',
  //
} as const
const pluginC = {
  name: 'pluginC',
  //
} as const

const plugins = {
  [pluginA.name]: '',
  [pluginB.name]: '',
  [pluginC.name]: '',
}
```

```js
const plugin = plugins["nonExistingPlugin"] 

// Gives me a type error as expected
// Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"nonExistingPlugin"' can't be used to index type '{ pluginA: string; pluginB: string; pluginC: string; }'.
//  Property 'nonExistingPlugin' does not exist on type '{ pluginA: string; pluginB: string; pluginC: string; }'.ts(7053)
```

```js
const plugin = plugins["plugin"] // Editor shows autocompletes for `pluginA`, `pluginB`, `pluginC`
```

Now if you also wanted to validate that each plugin also followed a `Plugin` type, you can do so by adding code like so:

```js
type Plugin = {
  name: string
  // other stuff
}

// This following line of code will throw an error if one of your plugins was not compatible with type Plugin
export const  _pluginsTypeCheck: {
  [key: string]: Plugin
} = plugins
```

Comment: Yes, indeed, it seems to work. However, how can I specify that `pluginX` is of type `Plugin`? So I want to do something like `const pluginX: Plugin = {...} as const`. Without "`: Plugin`" `as const` works, but I also want to make sure that `pluginX` implements interface `Plugin` :(

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `enum` for that:

`types.d.ts`

```js
export enum PluginNames {
   PluginA = 'pluginA',
   PluginB = 'pluginB',
   PluginC = 'pluginC',
}

interface Plugin {
   name: PluginNames
}
```

`src/plugins/pluginA/index.ts`

```js
const pluginA: Plugin = {
  name: PluginNames.PluginA
}

export default pluginA
```

`src/plugins/index.ts`

```js
import pluginA from "./pluginA"
import pluginB from "./pluginB"
...

export default {
  [PluginNames.PluginA]: pluginA
  [PluginNames.PluginB]: pluginB
  ...
}
```

You can also do the same using **type unions**:

```js
interface Plugin {
   name: 'pluginA' | 'pluginB' | 'pluginC'
}
```

Comment: It can be a solution, I also thought about it, however this is not exactly what I want. With this approach I will need to manually "sync" plugin names with this enum and watch that enum has the same number of values as the number of plugins. It would be great if I could "automate" this process using TypeScript.

Comment: I get your point but I believe there is no way to do so without tracking your plugins. Also since you are the one creating the plugins it makes sense for you to track them in my opinion. It won't be an automated process btw